# Question about indefinite integration and area

Tags: integration

Question $1$:$$\int\frac{f'(x)}{\sqrt{f(x)}}\mathrm dx= \int 4\,\mathrm dx $$ Then $f(1)=16,\  f(2)=?$

Question $2$:  The area of the region bounded by the curve $y=(x−a)^2$, the $x$-axis and the $y$-axis is  $\frac83$.  When $a>0,\ a=?$

Comment: Unintelligible question!

Comment: Please, try to write **clearly** your question *on paper*, and then read http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/93/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference  to learn how to properly write mathematics in this site.

Comment: i have found answers but I am not sure if I did them coreect...

Comment: sorry I'm new here :(((

Comment: Most probably very few people has a slightest idea what did you find answers to, @mark: your question is almost impossible to understand. And, after you learn a little how to post here, it'll be a good idea if you write down what you tried and what you got.

Comment: I believe that for 1. is:
$
log(f(x))=\int\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}dx=4x+c,
$
then
$
f(x)=e^C.e^{4x}=Ke^{4x}.
$
Since $f(1)=16$, then $Ke^4=16$, i.e., $K=16e^{-4}. Thus,
$
f(2)=16e^{-4}e^8=16e^4.
$ Is it?

Comment: @mark I edited your question. Please make sure that I did not change the context of your original question.

Comment: thanks it looks great how did you do this????

Comment: @EdsonSampaio sorry I forgot square root in the first question....

Comment: @mark Click the edit button and examine the changes that were made.  Also have a look at the rules for formatting mathematical equations in latex/mathjax [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 1):  Let $y=f(x).$  Then $f'(x)=y'=\dfrac{dy}{dx}.$  Then the integral is
$$\int\frac{f'(x)}{\sqrt{f(x)}}\mathrm dx=\int\frac{\frac{dy}{dx}}{\sqrt{y}}\mathrm dx=\int\frac{dy}{\sqrt{y}}=\int y^{-1/2}\mathrm dy=2y^{1/2}+C_1=2\sqrt{f(x)}+C_1.$$
Since it is given that $\int\frac{f'(x)}{\sqrt{f(x)}}\mathrm dx=4\int\mathrm dx$, then we have
$$2\sqrt{f(x)}+C_1=4\int\mathrm dx=4x+C_2.$$
Then we have
$$2\sqrt{f(x)}=4x+(C_2-C_1)\implies 2\sqrt{f(x)}=4x+C\implies \sqrt{f(x)}=2x+\frac{C}{2}.$$
Since it is given that $f(1)=16,$ then just plug this in to get $C$.  That is,
$$\sqrt{16}=2(1)+\frac{C}{2}\implies 4=2+\frac{C}{2}\implies 2=\frac{C}{2}\implies C=4$$
Now, we need to find $f(2)$.  Use the above equation to find it.  We have
$$\sqrt{f(2)}=2(2)+\frac42=4+2=6\implies f(2)=36.$$

For question 2): 
 This is a question about double integration.  Since $a>0$ then the graph $(x-a)^2$ is a shift of $x^2$ in the positive direction on the $x$ axis, and you are asked to find $a$ such that it the area bounded by $x$ axis, $y$ axis and $(x-a)^2$ is $\frac83$.  We have,
$$\int_0^a\int_0^{(x-a)^2}\mathrm dy\mathrm dx=\int_0^a(x-a)^2\mathrm dx=\int_0^a(x^2-2ax+a^2)\mathrm dx=\left[\frac{a^3}{3}-ax^2+xa^2\right]_0^a\quad =\frac{a^3}{3}-a^3+a^3=\frac{a^3}{3}$$
Since this area is equal to $\frac83$, then
$$\frac{a^3}{3}=\frac83\implies a^3=8\implies a=2.$$

Comment: thanks I have found my silly mistake :))) thanks again